# Styling problem. Cannot access specific button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, qtstylesheets

I want to add images to my buttons. I have all my styling in a separate file.

According to Qt docs https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types I should be able to access a specific button using the following syntax

```
QPushButton#my_button_name {}
```

but it does not seem to work.
Here is an example from my code:

```
# script with widgets and layouts

class Tab1():
    self.button1 = QPushButton()


# styling script

def button_style():
    return '''QPushButton#button1 {font:15px;}'''
```

I am misunderstanding something? I tried adding 'self.' to the name in the styling script but it does not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name selectors for stylesheets must be used by setting the [objectName](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop) property; python attribute naming is completely useless for this as Qt doesn't know anything about it.

In order to correctly apply the stylesheet as you want to, you need to *set* the object name:

```
    # ...
    self.button1 = QPushButton()
    self.button1.setObjectName('button1')
    self.setStyleSheet('QPushButton#button1 {font:15px;}')
```

Comment: Thank you! I wish Qt included this clarification in the official docs

Comment: To anyone wondering about this, Qt docs are very specific about the [selectors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types), as they clearly say that the `#` prefix is for the *object name*. No matter if it's Python or C++, the name of the variable is just a pointer to an object, it does not define anything about the object itself (nor Qt should know anything about that name), and an object could have many named variables pointing to it, or even none. There's no point in clarifying for this matter, since it's assumed a programmer should know this.